# Writing date to cell from userform changes order in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell and a userform. In the cell is date `12-10-2015`. When I load the userform, the date is loaded into a textbox. This textbox will say `12-10-2015`. Exactly how I need it. However, when I write it back to the cell, it changes the value to `10-12-2015`

Code:

On opening userform:

```
frmChangeData.txtBirthDate.value = shtData.cells(row, clmnBirthDate) 
'Loads 12-10-2015
```

On saving userform:

```
shtData.Cells(row, clmnBirthDate) = frmChangeData.txtBirthDate.Value
'Returns 10-12-2015
```

The above happens without changing anything in the userform. How to solve this?

Comment: Set the number format of the cell to Text. I suspect that the text is converted to a date when you copy it, and sometime there are trouble between dd-mm-yyyy and mm-dd-yyyy orders.

Comment: This looks like a formatting problem. What happens, if you use a date that can't be switched between european and american format (e.g. 13th December)?

Comment: Changing the format to text solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use format keyword for your puprose

```
Format(frmChangeData.txtBirthDate.value, "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CDate` to convert the date string to a true date value using your regional settings:

```
shtData.Cells(row, clmnBirthDate).Value = CDate(frmChangeData.txtBirthDate.Value)
```